# Excel Formatting - RoundUP

Tags: excel, formatting

Could you please help me with one excel exercise? Do you know by any chance if it's possible to change the format of values displayed in a given column (e.g. column highlighted in blue) to have decimal part hidden/removed and final figure rounded up? I know that I can add additional column and use e.g. ROUNDUP formula, however I am wondering whether it's possible to define a custom format to get exactly the same result in the source column without using formula or VBA?

Thank very much you in advance for your help,
Kamil

[Sample Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nefq.png)

Comment: If you format it, then it looks like what you want. BUT when you calculate it will use the original value - this can, and does, cause errors...

Comment: Thank you very much for quick answer. Unfortunately, when I am removing decimal places (there is 0 now), for 1.05 I am getting 1, but I wanted to have it always "rounded up" and see 2 instead. Default rounding works for example for 1.55 but for 1.05 or 1.40 it doesn't. Maybe it's not possible to change default settings?

Answer (score 0):

What you now describe in your comment needs the roundup() function so

```
=ROUNDUP(1.05,0)
```

See:
[image]

The ROUNDDOWN() function is also useful in some situations...

Comment: Ok, thank you. If there is no other option I will use formula.